# Cooker Hood Shorts When the Outer Cover Touches a Wall Bracket Installed to Stabilise the Cover

Tags: electrical

I have installed a cooker extractor hood which works fine with the vertical outer cover off. When I rest the hood cover on the extractor base and it touches a high level wall mounted bracket installed to steady the cover (not bolted to the cover) the MCB trips?

Comment: A picture would really be helpful.  Welcome to Home improvement.  Please take the tour at https://diy.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling you are in UK or Europe and your MCB includes RCD/RCBO functionality.**

The problem is that your device has residual current leakage, or what we in the states call a "ground fault".   It is leaking current in a way it should not, and which could stun/harm/kill a human. Being stunned unconscious onto a hot cooking surface would not be fun.

When you install the cover, you are causing the problem to manifest in a way that doesn't involve bloody mayhem.  This is a good thing.

The temptation would be to defeat the symptom, but the real problem is the hood is defective.  Sorry.

---

**if not, tripping the main circuit breaker *and not* the branch circuit breaker would require an arc flash brighter than the sun, and I'm pretty sure you would not be typing!